# How to make post request of an object with array property in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my api the raw data suggested this structure on making a post request.

```
{
    "empID": "",
    "fullname": "",
    "contactnumber": []
}
```

and in the api list here is some of the example structure:

```
{
    "empID": "DJS1003",
    "fullname": "Doe, John Smith",
    "contactnumber": [
        {
            "contactnumber": "123456789"
        },
        {
            "contactnumber": "321456879"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, my object data when making a post request looks like this:

```
contactnumber : Array[2]
    0:"444-1234"
    1:"0911-124-7854"
fullname:"John Doe"
empID:"1001"
```

**And i got this error that says:**

> contactnumber:[{non_field_errors: ["Invalid data. Expected a
>   dictionary, but got str."]},…]

**UPDATE**

Here is my `model.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    empID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length= 50, null=False)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ContactNumber(models.Model):
    empID = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name="contacts", to_field='empID', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    contactnumber = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

Here is my `serialzer.py`

```
class ContactsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = ContactNumber
            fields = (
                  'empID_id',
                  'contactnumber',
            )

class EmployeeListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      contacts = ContactsSerializer(many=True)

      class Meta:
            model = Employee
            fields = (
                  'empID',
                  'fullname',
            )
```

Comment: can you post your viewset and serializer code?

Comment: @Dap i just updated my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error is explicit enough I think.

What DRF expects is:

```
{
    "empID": "DJS1003",
    "fullname": "Doe, John Smith",
    "contactnumber": [
        {
            "contactnumber": "123456789"
        },
        {
            "contactnumber": "321456879"
        }
   ]
}
```

What you're sending:

```
{
    "empID": "101",
    "fullname": "John Doe",
    "contactnumber": [
        "444-1234",
        "0911-124-7854"
   ]
}
```

So, you need your JS to send an Array of dicts.
You could also tweak some relation field to make this happen but it's a bit more complex because you'll need both the employee ID and phone number to check unicity.

Comment: i am using angularjs to make a serialized data model for employee. and thanks for pointing the problem of array vs dict. Now all i need to do is make the contactnumber a dict and not an array.

Comment: thank you a lot. I really needed this answer, it worked really well.